# Can't pass variable as email body in Python script, email is not sending

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, boto3

I thought I had this email script worked out when I got the body to show a string but it seems that I can't pass a variable as a string the way I envisioned. "Hello world" works but when I try and pass `str(email_body)` this does not work.  Doing this `'''Hello World {}'''.format(email_body)` does not work either.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, once again any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
import smtplib

     try:
            sender = 'me@org'
            recipient = instance_contacttag
            subject = str(instance_nametag) + ' Tag Issues Detected'
            content = '''Hello World {}'''.format(email_body) #does not work when passing email_body as var
            mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) 
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login('example@one.com','12345678')
            header = 'To:' + recipient + '\n' + 'From:' \
            + sender + '\n'+'subject:' + subject  + '\n\n'
            content = header + str(content)
            print(content) #printing content to make sure there actually something 
            mail.sendmail(sender, recipient, content)
            

        except:
            print ("Error: unable to send email")

 
    # Sets variables for sns formatting
    # instanceids = instance_ids
    incorrect_keys = '\n'.join(return_value['incorrecttagkeys'])
    incorrect_values = '\n'.join(return_value['incorrecttagvalues'])
    missing_keys = '\n'.join(return_value['missingtagkeys'])
    missing_values = '\n'.join(return_value['missingtagvalues'])
    unknown_values = '\n'.join(return_value['unknowntagvalues'])
    
    email_body = """
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary of incorrect tags keys and/or values:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Incorrect Tag Keys    :   {incorrect_keys}
Incorrect Tag Values  :   {incorrect_values}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary of missing tags keys and/or values:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Missing Tag Keys     :   {missing_keys}
Missing Tag Values   :   {missing_values}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary of unknown values:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unknown Tag Values:
{unknown_values}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        """.format(incorrect_keys = incorrect_keys, 
                   incorrect_values = incorrect_values, 
                   missing_keys = missing_keys, 
                   missing_values = missing_values, 
                   unknown_values = unknown_values,
                  )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" and "email is not sending"?

Comment: I'm using this in a Lambda script and as the exception I'm printing out "unable to send out email" so I know the email did not go out.

Comment: Then remove the `try` and get the actual error message, or have the `except` print the _actual_ error message.